# Synchronous replication between two NAS Business Storage and Ubuntu 12.04.3

Tags: linux, file, ubuntu-12.04, replication, nas

My setup is I have two NAS setup. I can mount those NAS in a Linux Server (Ubuntu or Centos) and plan on writing on both NAS synchronously or replicate frmo one nas to the other one real-time.

Anyone have any ideas how can i do this? I've been looking at glusterfs but is there any other option i can use?

Thanks alot for the help.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for Superuser. http://superuser.com

Comment: Thanks. Will post it there!